# Sinatra app 404's when deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, rack, procfile

I am working with an app and am looking to deploy to heroku. Full source [here](https://github.com/samuelcouch/cheesy-parts).

The primary error that I am seeing is

`heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=cheesyparts.herokuapp.com request_id=25d2dbb5-e13a-4146-bb3a-9386f997c44c fwd="54.234.191.55" dyno=web.1 connect=2 service=3 status=404 bytes=417`

Locally when I attempt to lauch via [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) the same issue occurs. However, I am able to launch the server and run it if I use the `ruby parts_server_control.rb run`. Any tip is appreciated.

The `config.ru` looks like this

```
require './parts_server'
run Sinatra::Application
```

and the control script `parts_server_control.rb` looks like:

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "daemons"
require "pathological"
require "thin"

Daemons.run_proc("parts_server", :monitor => true) do
  require "parts_server"

  Thin::Server.start("0.0.0.0", PORT, CheesyParts::Server)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control script is running the app class `CheesyParts::Server`, but your but your `config.ru` (used by `foreman` and Heroku) assumes the app written in the classic style and is using the class `Sinatra::Application`. See the [Sinatra docs on modular and classic application styles](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps). Since nothing is added to `Sinatra::Application` it is an “empty” app and so you will get 404 errors for any route.

The fix is to change the line

```
run Sinatra::Application
```

in your `config.ru` to

```
run CheesyParts::Server
```

so that that class will be used as the main app.

Comment: Good catch! That was it.